# How to make the active class based on URL in php?

Tags: php

I have a navbar

```
<?php 
function echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
  $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

  if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
    echo 'class="active"';
}

?>
<section id="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>          
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("index")?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("services")?>><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
          <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("information")?>><a href="information.php">Information</a></li>
          <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("contact")?>><a href="contact.php">Contact Info</a></li>      
        </ul>          
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active">Call Us Today! <br> (123) 456-789</li>            
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This works when the url is `mydomain.com/index.php` and rest.
The problem when I open my page `mydomain.com/` The home button is not active.
It only becomes active when i click on home. it redirects to `mydomain.com/index.php`

**Is there a way to set the home active when url is `mydomain.com/` or `mydomain.com/index.php`**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$activeTab = explode('/',ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'));

// loop through each tabs
$activeTabs = array("index", "services","information","contact"); // set home as 'index', but can be changed based of the home uri
foreach ($activeTabs as $folder){
$active[$folder] = ($activeTab[0] == $folder)? "active":"noactive";
}


<ul>
   <li <?=active("index")?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li <?=active("services")?>><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
          <li <?=active("information")?>><a href="information.php">Information</a></li>
          <li <?=active("contact")?>><a href="contact.php">Contact Info</a></li>      
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your html :

```
<li <?= echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```